# Check if element in array of elements has focus

Tags: jquery, focus

I'm trying to find if any element in an unknown amount of elements has focus

```
if($('#wrapper ul li a:focus')) # there are multiple a tags that are dynamically generated
```

Anyone know how it's done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#wrapper ul li a:focus').length // get the number of items that has focus

$('#wrapper ul li a:focus').eq(0) //get's the first matched element
```

so if you need to check if any element in a set of elements has focus

```
if($('#wrapper ul li a:focus').length){
// do something
}
```

Comment: You don't need `> 0` ;)

Comment: It's just an extra step of logic that's not required.  It produces the same result either way.